# refresh on a jface tree item has paint issues

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, treeviewer

refresh on a jface tree item has paint issues.
What I am trying is to refresh when a new item is added.

treeviewer.refresh(item) that item has many child items (many)[image]

Ultimately it refreshes, however somewhere after 7-10 seconds later. How to approach to debug this paint issue ?

Comment: SWT/JFace trees have performance issues with very large trees. Using `SWT.VIRTUAL` and `ILazyTreeContentProvider` may help.

Comment: many means how many ? Just wanted to know.

Comment: like around 100 items

Answer (score 0):

If you use `treeViewer.refresh(item, false);` then you should have some better performance.  Only the labels of the new items would be looked up and updated rather than all of the children's labels.

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/StructuredViewer.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-boolean-

Comment: I have optimized (string operations when fetching the labels were removed) some code relating to display of children's labels. Also I had to create new set of objects when faced with identical objects.